# Irreducible representation of matrix is isomorphic to direct product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

If $X$ is a finite dimensional irreducible representation of the matrix algebra of order $m$ over $A$, where $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field $F$, is it true that $X$ is isomorphic to the direct product of $m$ irreducible representations of $A$?

I think I can see why the RHS is also a simple representation of the matrix algebra. My attempt is to consider $m=2$ first and a nonzero element $x\in X$, then construct the set of matrices with all but one certain column is zero acting on $x$. However I am still confused and cannot find the desired irreducible representations. Maybe this is a wrong approach.

Any guidance is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidHill Thanks. My bad, I am quite new to this theory. Doesn't your $X$ not satisfy the hypothesis "finite dimensional irreducible representation" in my first sentence? When $m=1$, isn't it trivial? Because it means $X=A$, and as it is assumed to be irreducible, then $?X$ is isomorphic to $1$ irreducible representation of $A$ (which is itself). Am I skipping something?

Comment: @DavidHill Also, I think there is a fact saying that under the assumption here, every irreducible representation of this matrix algebra $M_m(A)$ is isomorphic to a minimal left ideal of $M_m(A)$. I am thinking maybe it is related to this.

Comment: When $m=1$ you are talking about representations of $A$. What are your conditions on $A$? If $A$ is not semi simple, then?